# How do I clear a result and prepare for the next in javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently having the problem of clearing an image for a item search, the names change perfectly fine but the item image will not. Here is my code

```
$.getJSON('php/search-items.php', {query: query}, function (jsonObj) {
                    $('#results').html(str);
                    handleJsonResponse(jsonObj, function (data) {
                        var allItems = data['allItems'];

                        allItems.sort(function (a, b) {
                            var keyA = a['price'], keyB = b['price'];
                            return keyB - keyA;
                        });

                        mAllItems = [];

                        for (var i1 = 0; i1 < allItems.length; i1++) {
                            var item = allItems[i1];

                            var image = item['image'], name = item['name'], price = getFormattedPrice(item['price']);

                            mAllItems.push({id: i1, name: name});

                            str += '<tr><td>' + image +'</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + price + ' <span class="item-price-change-btn" id="' + i1 + '">?</span></td></tr>';
                        }

                        $('#results').html(str);
                        $('.item-price-change-btn').on('click', itemPriceChangeHandler);
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Here is my PHP
 <!-- language: lang-js -->
    if($query = "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge"){
    $link = "https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5gZKKkPLLMrfFqWdY781lteXA54vwxgbjrkc5ZD3wLNLGcFVrYl6GrAS2x7y7g8PvupidzyRmuCUl4H6IzkSpwUYbC6zHyEM/360fx360f";
    
    $image = "<img src='" . $link . "' style='width: 100px; height: 100px;' alt='AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge' />";
}
<!-- End Code -->
Then repeats with an else if

Comment: What is your JSON result?

Comment: Mohammad, this is my PHP for JSON http://prntscr.com/b24k01

Comment: No, we need to JSON text to solving your problem.